# Can Youtube v3 API be used currently for retreiving data of channels that user is not associated with?

Tags: youtube-api

I want to know if we can use **Youtube V3** API to retrieve channel data, videos etc when the channel requested is not the authenticated user's own channel.

The documentation for v3 youtube api  (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#try-it) says "The list method returns a collection of zero or more channel resources that match the request criteria. At this time, this method does require an authenticated user, and the API only supports requests to retrieve information about the channel that is associated with the currently authenticated user."

Example in V2 it is http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/{user_name}, what is the **equivalent**  in **v3** ? Is it **available yet** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plan is to support retrieving both channel profile information and the ids for the uploads/favorites/playlist/etc. feeds for a given channel in v3. It's not quite yet supported, but should be around the time of the public launch. (Which, I can't commit publicly to a date for that at this time.)

Answer (score 4):

You can request a channel by ID e.g. Lady Gaga channel:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?id=UCNL1ZadSjHpjm4q9j2sVtOA&key=AIzaSyCR5In4DZaTP6IEZQ0r1JceuvluJRzQNLE&part=snippet,contentDetails

Comment: Hi Marius, Thanks. But my main intention was to get the channels not by using channel Id, instead using the user id. Looking for a way to get the list of channels given a user id. Once I get channel Id's it is possible to take playlists and videos of playlist using v3 api.